# Installing Bosh on Cloud foundry gives error

Tags: cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

I am newbie to Cloud foundry and was looking for Autoscaling app in Opensource CF.

After setting out research found that Bosh v2 provides this capability and now I am trying to install Bosh V2 on Linux machine using links https://bosh.io/docs/cli-v2-install/
[http://bosh.io/docs/cli-v2/](https://bosh.io/docs/cli-v2/)
https://ottenwbe.github.io/bosh-install/manual-deployment.html,

After following steps mentioned, when I  `bosh –v`, I get the following error `-bash: bosh: command not found`. Could someone please help me realize where I am going wrong and find possible solution? Thanks in advance

Comment: Most likey installation raises error or warning you didnt notice, or the folder bosh got installed is not in the path. Con sider setting a [mcve] because for far there is no way to give a concrete answer.

Comment: I believe the OSS Autoscaler is here -> https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/app-autoscaler

Answer (score 0):

> [BOSH](https://bosh.io/docs/) is an open source project that offers a tool chain for release engineering, deployment and life-cycle management of large-scale distributed services.

BOSH autoscaler (https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/bosh-scaler-boshrelease ?) can scale BOSH deployments, for example number instances of [diego-cell](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/architecture/#diego-cell) on which apps are running.

To scale apps use https://github.com/cloudfoundry/app-autoscaler (what Daniel Mikusa mentioned).